# Three tables side by side in the center of page

Tags: tables, floats, subfloats

I have three tables I put side by side. I used \subfloat

The problem is that the tables are not in the center

Any solution to force the tables to be in the center.[image: ex]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Try using `\begin{center} ...\end{center}` and place your code for tables inside this environment? `\centering` also helps, but in this case the first one is the best option.

Comment: Thank you so much . I tried your solution but it does not work with me . I am using \documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

Comment: Did you check this https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions ? @J123

Comment: Yeah. Several times, but I could not find I any solution to this issue

Comment: @J123 Please, disclose what other packages you use. My example works with the elsevier-class on my system. Also, check that you system is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the three tabulars side by side in a center-environment. You may also try to reduce the fontsize to `\small` if your tables are to wide to fit within the margins.

[image]

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\small    %% <<--------- Reduce fontsize if tables are to wide to fit within the margins 
\begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|}

13&0.93&9.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&9.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&9.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&9.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&12.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&9.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&11.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&13.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&10.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&9.5&0.47\\
\hline
13&0.93&9.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&9.5&0.47\\
\hline
 \end{tabular}
 \begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|}

13&0.93&9.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&9.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&9.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&9.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&12.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&9.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&11.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&13.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&10.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&9.5&0.47\\
\hline
13&0.93&9.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&9.5&0.47\\
\hline
 \end{tabular}
 \begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|}

13&0.93&9.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&9.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&9.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&9.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&12.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&9.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&11.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&13.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&10.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&9.5&0.47\\
\hline
13&0.93&9.5&0.47\\
13&0.93&9.5&0.47\\
\hline
 \end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much . I tried your solution but it does not work with me . I am using \documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

Comment: @J123 Strange, I change my MWE to use `\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}` and it worked without a hitch. Please, disclose the other packages in your preamble.

Comment: Yeah. It is working now.

Comment: Yeah. helped . I marked it. thank you.

Comment: @J123 My pleasure!